# Failed to provision revision for container app 'app-name'. Error details: Opearation expired. (Code: ContainerAppOperationError)

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-apps

I am trying to create a new Azure container apps using ARM template.

When deployment, I face this issue

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ContainerAppOperationError","message":"Failed to provision revision for container app 'ca-dpsauth-ppe-cus-01'. Error details: Operation expired."}]}

[image]

I looked into the troubleshotting guide, but could find none related to this.

Thanks for the answers / suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the operation again, could just be a temporary issue. Can you try via the CLI with the same subscription to see if this is a portal issue.

Remember, if this is a live site issue you can always open a support ticket from the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because the referenced ImagePullSecret ca-dpsauth-xxx-xxx-01-xxxxxxxxxxx.azurecr.io was not found in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and implemented a workaround

In our case, when using "passwordSecretRef" which points to a "keyVaultUrl" The creation fails on the first but the second run (update) works.

We implemented a workaround which replaces the "keyVaultUrl" by a regular plaintext dummy password and on a following run replacing this by the actual  keyvault reference.

Unfortunately - at least on the container-apps-jobs endpoint - azure recently implemented a password validation check (within the same API version *rolleyes*) so the dummy password is not accepted anymore here.

2 Months ago a already opened a ticket on azure regarding this ticket but they asked me questions which have nothing to do with the issue and asked for enabling debugging flags in the API call which are not available on that specific endpoint. The ticket ended up closing.

Now since our workaround does not work around anymore, i've opened a new ticket with more details how to reproduce by a simple API call to not to disturb them by some middle-ware :)

However, they did not answered on that support request since days.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue while provisioning in terraform. It seems the resource is getting created to some point, but never completes fully. If I try to create it via portal it says deployed successfully, but after inspecting the resource, provisioning status is `unknown`.

edit:
I was able to provision it by deleting container app env and recreating it (via portal), my only hunch why it was failing previously is because I had it created via `az containerapp env create` using combination of `--infrastructure-resource-group` and `--infrastructure-subnet-resource-id` parameters, which required subnet to be delegated:

> (ManagedEnvironmentSubnetDelegationError) The subnet of the environment must be delegated to the service 'Microsoft.App/environments'.

and when creating it via Azure portal contrary to the above it was failing to provision until I removed the subnet delegation:

```json
        "statusMessage": "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",\"message\":\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"ManagedEnvironmentSubnetIsDelegated\",\"message\":\"AgentPoolProfile subnet with id /subscriptions/b95a1d5a-14d1-44cf-86c1-284ede8dac0c/resourceGroups/infrastructure/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/prod/subnets/container_app_env cannot be used as it's a delegated subnet. Please check https://aka.ms/adv-network-prerequest for more details.\"}]}}",
```